# How to translate str() to discord.Member? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

File:
78573462558784356

#that's an id

async def:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    with open("createteam.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file: # id is in a file
        author_id = file.read() #the id in str()
        author_user = ???author_id.User??? #how to translate a str(id) to discord.user
        author_member = ???author_id.Member??? #how to translate a str(id) to discord.member
```

Comment: This question I had when I started to learn discord.py, and I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 All you need is the id of a user.

2 If you need to get a variable discord.User, you use bot.get_user(id).

3 If you need to get a variable discord.Member, you use message.guild.get_member(id).

Where message.guild is a server where the message is sent

P.S every time you need to translate str() int() or something else into a variable that a bot can read, you need to use bot.get_ or guild.get_. There are all get_: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=get_&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Answer (score 0):

You can use `discord.utils.get()` for getting the user.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    with open("createteam.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
        author_id = file.read()
    member = discord.utils.get(payload.message.guild.members, id=int(author_id))
```

So you can do whatever you want with the `member`.